# Toggle для соседнего дива в общем

Tags: jquery, toggle

Есть куча блоков с одинаковыми стилями

```
<div class='totall'>
<a class='link'>text</a>
<div class='opis' style="display:none;"> text text text
</div>
</div>
```

требуется через клик $('.link').click(function() 
менять через toggle видимость

пробовал так

```
$('.link').click(function()
{
  $(this).closest('.opis').toggle( "slow" );
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меняем `closest` на `next` и усё.

Проблема с `closest` в том, что он будет искать ближайший подходящий элемент из числа следующих: **сам выбранный элемент, его родитель, его прародитель**, а не ближайший среди соседних элементов

```js
$('.link').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.opis').toggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='totall'>
  <a class='link'>text</a>
  <div class='opis' style="display:none;"> text text text</div>
</div>
<div class='totall'>
  <a class='link'>text2</a>
  <div class='opis' style="display:none;">text2 text2 text2</div>
</div>
<div class='totall'>
  <a class='link'>text3</a>
  <div class='opis' style="display:none;">text3 text3 text3 </div>
</div>
<div class='totall'>
  <a class='link'>text4</a>
  <div class='opis' style="display:none;"> text4 text4 text4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Здесь работает
у меня в простом хтмл файле нет(

Comment: кстати $(this).parent('.totall').closest.('.opis').toggle("slow"); тоже должно было бы работать?

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк `Здесь работает у меня в простом хтмл файле нет(` -  видимо из-за динамического html. Попробуйте `$('.totall').on('click', '.opis', function(){ ... `

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк не будет тут `closest` работать. Я написал почему. он действует на себя и на родителей... а не на ближайший любой

Comment: понял почему не работало... я вместо того чтобы скрипт засунуть поближе к </body> всунул его в <head> секцию. Спасибо огромное за помощь и еще больше за инфу о клозест!

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк если нужна инфа по функциям jquery на русском - заглядывайте сюда http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/   например http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Работа_с_набором_элементов (и остальные страницы тоже). Вроде хорошо там описано всё

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод `next()`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.link').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.opis').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='totall'>
  <a class='link'>Click</a>
  <div class='opis' style="display:none;"> text text text
  </div>
</div>
<div class='totall'>
  <a class='link'>Click</a>
  <div class='opis' style="display:none;"> text text text
  </div>
</div>
<div class='totall'>
  <a class='link'>Click</a>
  <div class='opis' style="display:none;"> text text text
  </div>
</div>
```